# How to use Tor over Lan

Tags: proxy, lan, tor

I have a laptop running Ubuntu 12.04 with Tor. Now with following credentials Tor works fine with any SOCKS5 supported apps.

```
Host: 127.0.0.1
Port: 9050
```

This laptop is connected with WiFi router (192.168.1.10). I have an iPad which is connected to same WiFi router (192.168.1.5). Now I used following credential in iPad WiFi proxy settings.

```
Host: 192.168.1.10
Port: 9050
```

But this doesn't work. I think Tor is not listening over LAN. How can I make Tor listen to whole LAN network? Or 0.0.0.0?

Answer (score 6):

Open torrc file, if you use ubuntu its in /etc/tor/torrc

and edit this line

```
SocksListenAddress 127.0.0.1
```

to this:

```
SocksListenAddress 192.168.1.10
```

Then just restart tor using

```
service tor restart
```

Answer (score 1):

In `Vidalia Control Pannel` , open `Settings`. Go to `Advanced` tab. In front of `Address`, type your IP address (192.168.1.10).

Comment: Isn't that just the control port, though and not the listening port?